# Check for non-numeric inputs in a C++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

How do you check for non-numeric input using C++? I am using cin to read in a float value, and I want to check if non-numerical input is entered via stdin. I have tried to use scanf using the %d designator, but my output was corrupted. When using cin, I get the correct format, but when I enter, a string such as "dsffsw", I get an infinite loop.
The commented code was my attempt to capture the float, and type cast it as string, and check if it is a valid float, but the check always comes up false.

I have tried using other methods I have found on the message boards, but they want to use scanf in C and not cin in C++. How do you do this in C++? Or in C if it is not feasible.

```
while (!flag) {
        cout << "Enter amount:" << endl;
        cin >> amount;


    cout << "BEGIN The amount you entered is: " << strtod(&end,&pend) << endl;

        //if (!strtod(((const char *)&amount), NULL))   {
        //  cout << "This is not a float!" << endl;
        //  cout << "i = " << strtod(((const char *)&amount), NULL) << endl;
        //  //amount = 0.0;
        //}

        change = (int) ceil(amount * 100);

        cout << "change = " << change << endl;

        cout << "100s= " << change/100 << endl;
        change %= 100;
        cout << "25s= " << change/25 << endl;
        change %= 25;
        cout << "10s= " << change/10 << endl;
        change %= 10;
        cout << "5s= " << change/5 << endl;
        change %= 5;
        cout << "1s= " << change << endl;
        cout << "END The amount you entered is: " << amount << endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You're missing a few declarations for variables in this snippet.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html

Comment: Most of the time in C++, your read statements need to be in the conditional of a while loop.  Then failure will cause the while loop to terminate instead of your program.

Answer (score 1):

```
int amount;

cout << "Enter amount:" << endl;

while(!(cin >> amount)) {
   string garbage;
   cin.clear();
   getline(cin,garbage);
   cout << "Invalid amount. "
        << "Enter Numeric value for amount:" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I like `getline(cin, garbage)`, it's a bit more obvious than the mouthful that is `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`. Declaration of garbage should be moved inside the while loop however.

Answer (score 0):

I think you task relates to the so called **defensive programming**, one of it`s ideas is to prevent situations like one you described (function expects one type and user enters another).

I offer you to judge whether input is correct using method that returns **stream state** , which is `good()`,
so I think it will look something like this:

```
int amount = 0;
while (cin.good()) {
        cout << "Enter amount:" << endl;
        cin >> amount;
```